# Can ::google::protobuf::MessageLite be serialized by ::google::protobuf::Message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Can wire data, written by `::google::protobuf::MessageLite`-based runtime, be serialized by `::google::protobuf::Message`(which is a derived class of `MessageLite`), provided both use same form of `message` definintion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [protobuf wire format](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/) is independent of the runtime—or even the programming language—used to encode or decode it. You could serialize a message in C++ and parse it back in Java, or do the same with the lite and full C++ runtimes.

Within a given binary, most of the member functions that deal with serialization (like `ParseFromString` and `SerializeToString`, which the classes generated by protoc override) are [defined in `MessageLite`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/159306ba74fafc3f9b902bfdcb56ee542ffd7046/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.h), so you'd run the same code whether you call them on a `Message` or a `MessageLite`.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that serialization is inherited from lite. Just the the "full" version got more functionality, e.g.  tuple-like getters, or a printer function, and I had my doubts. So,  for debugging purposes I can use a non-Lite version  to automatically dump content of messages into text (like protoc utility can do)?

Comment: Yup! Note also that, while `Message::DebugString` gives nice, readable output since it uses reflection (in the form of descriptors) to get the names of fields and enums, `MessageLite::DebugString` can give you a string that's more limited but still useful - probably with tag numbers instead of field names